# Condensing down an awk / sed piped command

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have an ugly looking command that takes output from sensors and strips it of unneeded characters and decimal places, then prints it with awk with a trailing fahrenheit symbol. The command looks like this:

```
sensors -f | awk '/temp1/ { print $2 }' | sed 's/+//g' | awk '{ sub (/\..*/, ""); print $1 "°F" }'
```

Output from this command looks like this.

```
101°F
```

The command is a bit of a mess but it gets the job done, and considering my limited knowledge of awk and sed that is something to be said. I was hoping someone with a bit more knowledge could show me how this command could be condensed down, as I am unclear how to run an awk with a search pattern, followed by a replace, and print. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Output of sensors -f as requested.

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       +112.2°F  (crit = +203.0°F)
temp2:       +118.6°F  (crit = +221.0°F)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:      +119.0°F  (high = +212.0°F, crit = +212.0°F)
Core 1:      +121.0°F  (high = +212.0°F, crit = +212.0°F)
```

Comment: Add output of `sensors -f` to your question.

Comment: Updated with the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use use this single awk command instead:

```
sensors -f | awk '/temp1/ { gsub(/^\+|\.[[:digit:]]+/, "", $2); print $2 }'
```

**Output:**

```
112°F
```

`gsub(/^\+|\.[[:digit:]]+/, "", $2);` will replace any leading `+` or decimal values from the reported temperature.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be a way to do this in a far more simple command.

Answer (score 4):

```
# Posix
sensors -f | sed -e '/^temp1:[[:blank:]]\{1,\}[+]/ !d' -e 's///;s/F.*/F/'
# GNU
sensors -f | sed '/^temp1:[[:blank:]]+[+]/!d;s///;s/F.*/F/'
```

another sed approach

Answer (score 3):

With GNU sed:

```
sensors -f | sed -nE 's/^temp1: +\+([^.]+).[0-9]*(°F).*/\1\2/p'
```

Output:

```
112°F
```

Answer (score 2):

This is less messy:

```
sensors -f | awk '/temp1/{ printf "%d°F\n", $2 }'
```

It works, because awk begins parsing the string $2 at the beginning and stops if it doesn't fit the requirements anymore. So, as an example, `"+234.76abcd" * 1` is parsed to  the number 234.76. The same thing happens here when it looks for an integer to fill the %d in the format string.

I'd prefer:

```
sensors -f | awk '/temp1/{ print int($2) "°F" }'
```

Comment: Probably the most elegant solution I've seen for this. Thanks!